# Magento 2 jquery.mobile.custom.js:44 error

Tags: magento

Using custom theme for Magento2. I am creating navigation from backend by adding categories.

The problem I'm facing is with the sub-categories, `onMouseover` the sub-categories is not appearing.

I am getting error in console.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
at jquery.mobile.custom.js:44`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jQuery Mobile might not be compatible with jQuery Core 3. Page works when you downgrade to version 2.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

This also could be happening when another version of JQuery is loaded over the base version by some other modules and then due to compatibility issues jquery.mobile.custom.js starts getting undefined event properties of the mouse.

Please check version compatibiltiy.